# auto order posts of custom posttype by title

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

i have a custom posttype which has more than 50 posts.
i want to reorder alphabetically.
so that each time i post anything the system automatically reorders them within the posttype itself.
plz dont suggest post order plugin its drag and drop type and would be very very tedious .
I am putting the below code in the functions.php but it doesn't reorder the posts within the posttype.

```
<?php
    function alpha_order_classes( $query ){
        if ( $query->is_post_type_archive('Books') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        }  
    }    
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'alpha_order_classes' );
?>
```

Comment: which line shows the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'"?

Comment: the last } just before add_action

Comment: check the code before definition of 'function alpha_order_classes'

Comment: its works fine without this block of code...the moment i put this it gives error....is there any other way i can get the posts to reorder automatically

Comment: ok i added it after the whole code and it doesn't give error...but it doesn't work either